# Compiling a multiple sheet Excel Spreadsheet into pycel

Tags: pycel

TL;DR - trying to compile [this multi-sheet Pycel tests/fixture spreadsheet](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel/tree/master/tests/fixtures/excelcompiler.xlsx) (I'm particularly interested in capturing inter-sheet dependencies) using into Python code using Pycel

---

## The Problem

The helpful Pycel example in the example/example.py in the [Pycel repository](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel) runs perfectly and produces a handy .gexf graph, however, I can't work out how to compile a multi-sheet Spreadsheet (in my use case there is terrifying inter-sheet dependencies!) using Pycel.

@Stephen Rauch mentioned that "Pycel does really deal with sheets. It works with cells. Those cells can come from any sheet in the workbook" in [this Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365359/python-pycel-issues), however, I couldn't find any detail on this in the Pycel repo or in prior questions.

---

## What I tried

I tried compiling the spreadsheet included in tests/fixtures/excelcompiler.xlsx as this is multi-sheet and it only seems to compile for Sheet1 as the resulting plot is empty (Sheet1 is empty).

```py
import pycel
excel = pycel.ExcelCompiler('excelcompiler.xlsx')
excel.plot_graph()
```

Is it possible to use Pycel to compile dependencies between sheets?

---

I'm currently trying to compile this [Excel spreadsheet tool](https://www.seai.ie/publications/DEAP-4.2.0-TGDL-Example-A.xlsx)<sup>1</sup> into Python for modelling purposes<sup>2</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> For more details see [The Irish National Building Energy Rating Assessment](https://www.seai.ie/home-energy/building-energy-rating-ber/support-for-ber-assessors/domestic-ber-resources/) 

<sup>2</sup> Running Dublin-wide simulations of the energy/carbon impacts of different building-policy decisions</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Pycel compiles multi-sheet Excel spreadsheets easily.  Pycel's function `pycel.ExcelCompiler` is lazy and so doesn't actually compile Excel into Python until explicitly asked to do so via `excel.evaluate('Result!E16')}` (i.e. evaluate some cell)

---

## In detail

I tried:

```py
excel = pycel.ExcelCompiler(filename='deap.xlsx')

# for viewing in gephi (quicker runtime)
excel.export_to_gexf('deap.gexf')

# or via matplotlib
excel.plot_graph()
```

And my result was an empty graph.

I then tried (as in the example at [pycel](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel)):

```py
excel = pycel.ExcelCompiler(filename='deap.xlsx')

print(f"TotalDeliveredEnergy is {excel.evaluate('Result!E16')}")

# for viewing in gephi (quicker runtime)
excel.export_to_gexf('deap.gexf')

# or via matplotlib
excel.plot_graph()
```

And this worked!

In other words, my issue was that I was trying to plot a Pycel relationship before it had been evaluated - Pycel is lazy and so only compiles Excel to Python when called upon with `excel.evaluate`.